# Angular cli build without converting scss/less to .css or .js

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I have angular 4 app which uses less as a preprocessor. When I do "ng build", it converts all my less files to the .js files which load these stylesheets. I want to build this application in such a way that it doesn't generate/convert the scss files.

Is there any way where i can avoid this conversion? I followed the documentation of angular-cli but no luck.

Any pointer would be helpful.

Comment: How can the browser use your styles if they're not css? less and scss are not css and the browser cannot interpret them.

Comment: I will integrate this application into some other application. I will load manually. into that application I will use that application variable defination will do build into that application.

Comment: Then the CLI is the wrong tool, sounds like you're making a Lib not an App

Comment: Thanks, It app as it needs to run standalone as well.

Comment: If you have scss then it cannot run standalone

Answer (score 0):

You can try

> ng build --ec.

This will compress the styles to a styles.css and then you can include it in your index file.

Comment: I do not want to convert into css.

Answer (score 0):

You can put scss in the assets folder and load from there, ng build does not touch assets folder

Answer (score 0):

Here is the procedure to switch to CSS:

1/ Delete `node_module`

2/ In `angular.json` file

2.1/ Edit this line

```
"schematics": {
 "@schematics/angular:component": {
    "style": "less"
   }
},
```

To this line

```
"projectType": "application",
  "schematics": {
     "@schematics/angular:component": {
       "style": "css"
      }
  },
```

2.2/ Edit this line (always on angular.json)

```
"styles": [
    "src/styles.less"
 ],
```

With this line

```
 "styles": [
     "src/styles.css"
 ],
```

For information: There ara 2 lines `"src/styles.less"` on angular.json (Don't forget to modify the two lines)

3/ Close all open windows on visual studio code

4/ `npm i`